# I am Trying to create my first Django Project on VS Code and I cant figure out how properly install the packages needed

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, python-module

I am a beginner programmer who was trying to create his first project in VS Code. I installed in the Windows Powershell Django and activated a virtual environment as followed through the following pages:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/windows/

And also tried to install it on VS Code directly following this tutorial on YT:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wfu5dPbiyKA

however, the following problems occur when I check the files in VS Code

wsgi.py:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

This line throws the following warning:

```
Import "django.core.wsgi" could not be resolved from source
```

and the same error is thrown in the urls.py file and asgi.py file for the following:

Asgi: `from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application`
Urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
```

After some research, I discovered that either I installed incorrectly Django into my computer or VS Code, or either I can install them individually. However, neither have worked as when I try to check the status of Django, it says that the module doesn't exist. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/windows/ you should have Python installed, created a virtual environment, entered the environment with `...\> project-name\Scripts\activate.bat` and then installed django with `pip install django`.
After this, you should be able to use the `django-admin --version` command in your terminal.

After this is working, you can start a django project following the official tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/

Create the project with `django-admin startproject projectname` and start the server with `python manage.py runserver`.

VS Code should have nothing to do with that. You can also use the terminal inside VS Code to run all the commands, but I would recommand using the original windows terminal for the start - just to be sure its working.